# Soft question: seeking online course reference for CS

Tags: image-processing, discrete-signals, compressive-sensing

Is there a good online course (with video) for Image/Signal Processing or Matrix Computations that includes a section on the principles of Compressed Sensing?

Comment: Search coursera for Duke University image processing, nice course. If you just want video lectures search for ucf computer vision, Dr Mobarak Hossain, in youtube.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: There is no shortage of links to go through:
http://www.quora.com/Compressed-Sensing/What-are-some-good-resources-for-learning-about-compressed-sensing

If anyone can suggest a good one from experience I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Coursera has many courses available. Please check https://www.coursera.org/course/digital

Answer (score 1):

There are some good links at the Nuit Blanche website:
[Nuit Blanche](http://nuit-blanche.blogspot.ca/p/teaching-compressed-sensing.html)
In particular the course by Baraniuk and Duarte [CNX Course](http://cnx.org/content/col11133/latest/)

Answer (score 1):

There are some matlab [codes](http://compsens.eecs.umich.edu/sensing_tutorial.php) on CS.

Answer (score 1):

Here it's a set of lectures taught by professor Emmanuel Candés at Cambridge. [Video & Audio](http://www.sms.cam.ac.uk/collection/1117766/)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from *Coursera* mentioned previously, I could also suggest **edX**: [ELEC301x Discrete Time Signals and Systems](https://www.edx.org/course/ricex/ricex-elec301x-discrete-time-signals-1032) from Rice University. Fairly good introduction to DSP.